# How to frame a URL in parent component and pass it to child component using react?

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of notifications of types "item_created", "item_deleted", "item_updated", and so on. For the notification of type "item_created", I have to link the item name to the page that contains it.

I have a `ParentComponent` where I get the notifications and store them in state notifications. From `ParentComponent`, I pass the notifications state to notifications component.

This notifications component has a `NotificationItem` component which gets each notification from notifications component.

Within the `NotificationItem` component, I check for the notification type, and then I display text to the user based on that notification type.

If the notification type is "item_created", then I need to display the item name to the user. Clicking the item name should redirect the user to `'/path/item_id?param=param_id url'`.

Now this `item_id` and `param_id` are in the notification type "item_created".

There are 3 cases to consider:

1. If the user is viewing notifications from the home page (i.e., path is '/'), then the link to the URL would be framed as `'/path/item_id?param=param_id'`.
2. If the path equals `/path/item_id` (note this `item_id` is different from notification `item_id`), then the link to the URL should be framed as `'/path/item_id?param=param_id'`.
3. if the path equals `'/path/item_id/another_path'` (*note this `item_id` is different from notification `item_id`), then the link to the URL should be framed as `'/path/item_id/another_path?param=param_id'`.

## The Problem

I read the `location.pathname` from the notifications component and frame URL there and pass it to notification type equals "item_created". When I click the item name, I get the error failed prop to is undefined for Link. I think this is because after clicking the link, the notification component unmounts.

But if I frame the URL in `ParentComponent`, how can I get access to `item_id` and `param_id`?

## The Code

```
class ParentComponent extends react.purecomponent {
     this.state = {
         notifications: [],
     };

     render = () => {
         return (
             <Notifications
                    notifications={this.state.notifications}
                    location={this.props.location}
              />
         );
     }
}

export default function Notifications(props) {
    return (
        {props.notifications.map((notification) => {
            return (
                <NotificationItem
                    notification={notification}
                    location={props.location}/>
            );
        }
    )
  }

  class NotificationItem extends React.PureComponent {
       render = () => {
           switch (notification.type) {
               case 'item_created': {
                   let link_path;
                   const path = this.props.location.pathname;
                   if (path === '/') {
                       link_path = 
                           `/path/${notification.attributes.item_id}? 
                            param=${notification.attributes.param_id}`;
               }
               return (
                   <Notification
                       text={<span>{notification.name}<Link to= 
                       {link_path}>Click the link</Link></span>}/>
               );
           }
       }
   }
```

Could someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your Link error with the undefined `to` prop is this:

```
let link_path;
```

A let variable is a block level variable so it only exists inside the curly braces of that switch case.

Either change it to:

```
var link_path
```

Or move the declaration up before your switch case.